# In Apps Script, can I get the timestamp that a Google Form was ORIGINALLY submitted?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

We have a Google Form where users submit details of projects they want my colleagues to work on. Data from the Forms comes through to a Google Sheets spreadsheet. The responses can be edited by whoever has the right URL i.e. even though Person A submits the form, Person B can edit it later.

I'm not a developer but managed to use some Apps Script I found on this site to harvest the URL and have it displayed as a link in Google Sheets. This works well.

For a separate task, I would now like to display the data in the order in which the Forms were ORIGINALLY submitted. The problem is that whenever a form is edited, the timestamp is updated. This means that even if a Form was first submitted months ago, if it was edited yesterday it appears at the bottom of the list.

This is the code I'm using to get the edit URL in Google Sheets. I'll be honest, I'm not techie enough to understand it properly, but it appears to use a timestamp value which gets updated. Is there any way to adapt it to find the original timestamp and use that instead? It should still generate the correct URL, but would allow me to sort the data in the right order.

```
/*
 * Global Variables
 */

// Form URL
var formURL = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/ID_of_our_Google_Form/edit';
// Sheet name used as destination of the form responses
var sheetName = 'Form responses 3';
/*
 * Name of the column to be used to hold the response edit URLs 
 * It should match exactly the header of the related column, 
 * otherwise it will do nothing.
 */
var columnName = 'Edit Url' ;
// Responses starting row
var startRow = 2;

function getEditResponseUrls(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
  var columnIndex = headers[0].indexOf(columnName);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);
  for(var i = startRow-1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][0] != '' && data[i][columnIndex] == '') {
      var timestamp = data[i][0];
      var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(timestamp);
      if(formSubmitted.length < 1) continue;
      var editResponseUrl = formSubmitted[0].getEditResponseUrl();
      sheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndex+1).setValue(editResponseUrl);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: About `In Apps Script, can I get the timestamp that a Google Form was ORIGINALLY submitted?`, I think that when Forms API is used, this can be achieved. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your title and your showing script. Can I ask you about the details of your current issue and your expected result? By the way, about `var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(timestamp);`, in this case, `timestamp` of the last modified time can be used. Is this not your expected result?

Comment: @Tanaike The last modified time is what I have now. But a Form that was submitted 6 months ago may have been updated yesterday, so it will have yesterday's timestamp. I'm wondering whether there is a way to get FIRST modified timestamp, or ORIGINAL submitted timestamp, or whatever it might be called. That's the value I would like to sort my data on.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, about `In Apps Script, can I get the timestamp that a Google Form was ORIGINALLY submitted?`, I think that when Forms API is used, this can be achieved. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your title and your showing script.

Comment: About `I'm wondering whether there is a way to get FIRST modified timestamp, or ORIGINAL submitted timestamp, or whatever it might be called.`, the created time can be retrieved by Forms API as I have already mentioned in my 1st comment. That is `createTime` in Forms API.